# SocialEngine - Redirects in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, socialengine

I've completed a fresh install of SocialEngine PHP in my private server.

I also need now to install Moodle, and access in the following way to it:

http://www.example.com/moodle

SocialEngine creates its own .htaccess file, so every time I try to access the moodle directory, I got a "Page Not Found. The page you have attempted to access could not be found." because the redirection forces it to search moodle inside SocialEngine plugins, and I want it to redirect to a /moodle/ directory inside /httpdocs.

I am very noob with .htaccess options, I need a hint about what can I do.

The .htaccess content is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size
```

Any suggestion or tip, please?

Thank you very much in advance!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would exclude the moodle-folder in every rewrite and check if it works. After it is working I would remove it in every rule where you don't really need it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Get rid of index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

# Rewrite all directory-looking urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

# Try to route missing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
RewriteRule . - [L]

# If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/moodle
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size
```